# Importing SQL dump in devspace deployment using Helm component charts

Tags: devspace

When I was using `skaffold` I just had a `Dockerfile` that was used to do the following:

```
FROM postgres:13-alpine
EXPOSE 5432
COPY *.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

This would copy a dev SQL dump to load into a local dev database as it was spinning up.

Now that I'm using `devspace` and using Helm [Component Charts](https://devspace.sh/component-chart/docs/configuration/reference), I've been able to get rid of dev manifests and looking to get rid of this Postgres `Dockerfile` since it isn't doing much except importing this file in.

Looking at the Component Chart documentation, I'm not seeing how to add a parameter to copy the local SQL dump into the container in `deployment` phase.

Any suggestions, or should I be using [Hooks](https://devspace.sh/cli/docs/configuration/hooks/basics#lifecycle-events) and targeting a specific lifecycle event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should be using the `after:initialSync:*` hook, i.e. if your sql dump file is part of the file sync, it will be uploaded during initialSync, then the hook can be used to import the dump.